# How to group contiguous sections of a collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My sorted by date collection looks like this:

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "date": new Date("2021-01-09T01:00:00.000Z"),
    "cost": 0.25
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "date": new Date("2021-01-09T02:25:00.000Z"),
    "cost": 0.25
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "date": new Date("2021-01-09T03:04:00.000Z"),
    "cost": 0.25
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "date": new Date("2021-01-09T03:30:00.000Z"),
    "cost": 0.45
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "date": new Date("2021-01-09T04:15:00.000Z"),
    "cost": 0.45
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "date": new Date("2021-01-09T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "cost": 0.25
  }
```

I want to group it by `cost`, but I want to do it for contiguous sections, meaning duplicate costs from different time frames should NOT be grouped together. The result I am looking for from the above collection is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 0.45,
    "dates": [
      ISODate("2021-01-09T03:30:00Z"),
      ISODate("2021-01-09T04:15:00Z")
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 0.25,
    "dates": [
      ISODate("2021-01-09T01:00:00Z"),
      ISODate("2021-01-09T02:25:00Z"),
      ISODate("2021-01-09T03:04:00Z")
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 0.25,
    "dates": [
      ISODate("2021-01-09T05:00:00Z")
    ]
  }
]
```

Just grouping by cost is a piece of cake with

```
...
$group: {
      "_id": "$cost",
      dates: {
        $push: "$date"
      }
    }
...
```

But how to make it not lump in all duplicate costs from other time frames into the same array? Here is my Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cSqkbr5Uoab

Comment: *meaning duplicate costs from different time frames* in which timeframe you want to group? 5 mins, 10 mins, hourly, daily, etc?

Comment: @turivishal It's not hourly or daily or otherwise, it's the time frame in which a given cost is present. Notice how in my question the 0.25 cost is from `2021-01-09 01:00:00` to `2021-01-09 03:04:00`. Then it changes to 0.45 from `2021-01-09 03:30:00` to `2021-01-09 04:15:00`. And then it goes back to 0.25 from `2021-01-09 05:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

If the time frame granularity is 1h here it is:

```
db.d.aggregate([ {$project:{dateOnly:{$substr:["$date",0,14]} ,date:1, cost:1 }  }  , {$group:{_id:{d:"$dateOnly",c:"$cost"} , dates:{$push:"$date"}   }}    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Time granularity can be in the milliseconds actually.

Comment: dateOnly:{$substr:["$date",0,19]  will provide you uniqness to sec and so one ...